# Prevent users from changing certain text in asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have some users who would like to include a deadline date for a payment in an e-mail template. This e-mail template will be sent out regularly to users who has not paid within a certain timeframe + only until the deadline date is reached, meaning the e-mail will not be sent out past this point. The admin can change the deadline to a future date when they want and the e-mails will start going out again automatically.

The admins can also edit the e-mail templates and this is where my problem arises. When they load in an e-mail template they will of course also be able to see, change or delete the deadline date. If they change the format or delete the date it will no longer be able to update the date since it's depending on some codebehind checking for a certain date and format (when they set a deadline date as admin it will be changed on the template).

Is it possible to somehow prevent the admins from changing the deadline dates in the e-mail template? Perhaps if you could insert another control in the asp:Textbox and making it read-only? Or do you have another solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the format of the template, how do the users edit it?

Comment: I'd say it depends on how you're doing editing of such template. If it's a plain asp:TextBox then AFAIK you have to use another read-only control or one of techniques described for example in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181417/how-to-make-only-some-text-in-a-text-box-read-only-while-allowing-the-rest-to-be) (pretty rough, I have to say). Best would be to write a proper editor (with JavaScript) but it may be overkill. You may also simply ignore that change or to do not write it in template at all (leave a placeholder for that).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I ended up making a tag to insert in the template by the users. There's no way i can make sure that they won't delete the tag but at least now it pulls the date from the tag name.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with some coding tricks as follows :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string origValue = string.Empty;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        origValue = textBox1.Text;
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("12/10/2015"))
        {
            origValue = textBox1.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = origValue;
        }
    }
}
```