# AngularJS not working in JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

This is my first time using JSFiddle and this is my first atempt at Angular as well.

I have tried all of the suggestions from other posts but can't seem to get this JSFiddle working.

```
var partialApp = angular.module("partialApp", []);

partialApp.directive('partialReadonly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
                var readOnlyLength = attrs["partialReadonly"].length;
                if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
                    && ((elem[0].selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
                    || ((elem[0].selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            $(window).load(function () {
                elem[0].value = attrs["partialReadonly"];
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/codemonkeytony/3ew5h6bf/3/

I'm putting this together to add to an answer I submitted for this question

[Partially read-only textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092700/partially-read-only-textbox/26111078#26111078)

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Select angular 1.2.1

Comment: First time..? I recommend start with something good. **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)** is one of them.. ;) jsBin is not bad as well.. Here is one.. http://plnkr.co/edit/oiJwq3295VkvyTGzlfsr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your console will show an error "undefined is not a function"

Your specific issue is that you have `elem.on` which is a jQuery thing. You need `$(elem).on` or a different binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ew5h6bf/8/

Comment: thx @hassassin. that works too. I tried zsong suggestion of changing angular versions and that also worked. cheers :)