# Disable deletion of first letter of textbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Textbox first letter is populated automatically and the user can enter remaining letters in the textbox. But the user should not be able to delete the first letter which is populated on page load. The user can remove the letters which are written by him by using backspace,delete, or select all except the populated first letter.

```
<input type="text" id="nameId" value="Given Name"/>

$("#nameId").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 0 && (e.keyCode < 35 || e.keyCode > 40))
        || ($(this).get(0).selectionStart == 1 && e.keyCode == 8)) {
        return false;
    }
});

$("#nameId").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zfT2/2/)
, its fine except the selected delete.

Comment: I think this is what you want. Try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181417/how-to-make-only-some-text-in-a-text-box-read-only-while-allowing-the-rest-to-be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/1hyn47he/10/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="N" />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       var prefix = "N";
       var ctrlDown = false,shiftDown = false;
       var ctrlKey = 17, aKey = 65 , shiftKey = 16,rKey = 39,lKey = 37;

      // mange ctrl and shift key event make flag true/false
      $(document).keydown(function(e)
      {
         if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
         if (e.keyCode == shiftKey) shiftDown = true;
      }).keyup(function(e)
      {
         if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
         if (e.keyCode == shiftKey) shiftDown = false;
      });

      // if ctrl and shift flag ture and press A or right arrow key or left arrow key it return falsel
      $(document).on('keydown','#text',function(e){
         if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == aKey) || shiftDown && ((e.keyCode == rKey)) || shiftDown && (e.keyCode == lKey)) return false;
      });

      $(document).on('keyup','#text',function(e){
   // if useing right key move cursor to first position it auto move focus at last character in text box 

      if(e.keyCode == rKey || e.keyCode == lKey){
        if(this.selectionStart == 0){
           this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = $('#text').val().length; 
        }
      }

      if($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0){
        $(this).val(prefix);
      }
   });

   // using mouse click on to first position it auto move focus at last character in text box 
   $("#text").on("contextmenu click", function(e) {
      this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = $('#text').val().length;  
      e.preventDefault();
   });

   // using mouse click select all text it auto move focus at last character in text box 
   $( "#text" ).select(function() {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = $('#text').val().length;
  }); 

 });
```

Comment: Not working when you write characters at the beginning of input, you lose starting `N`

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('#text').on('select keydown contextmenu mousedown drop', function(e) {
   if(e.type == 'keydown' && this.selectionStart == 0 && this.selectionEnd == 0) {
      this.setSelectionRange(1, 1);
   }
   if((e.keyCode == 37 && (this.selectionStart == 1 || e.ctrlKey)) || (e.keyCode == 36) ||
      (e.keyCode == 8 && this.value.length == 1)|| (e.keyCode == 46 && this.selectionStart == 0) || e.type == 'drop') {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
   if(this.selectionStart == 0 &&
      this.selectionStart != this.selectionEnd) {
      this.setSelectionRange(1, this.selectionEnd);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="N" />
```

Comment: you can remove this prefix using delete button.

Comment: Perfect ! Better then accepted answer. Easily changed to not deleting first 2 characters. Thanks for efforts