# How to make first 3 letter of text in a text-box read-only inside of dynamic gridview asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi i have the same problem with this ticket but the only difference that the textbox is inside gridview that is not visible in pageload, it only visible when particular condition will be met.

[How to make only some text in a text-box read-only while allowing the rest to be edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181417/how-to-make-only-some-text-in-a-text-box-read-only-while-allowing-the-rest-to-be)

ive tried the code below but it doesnt run correctly
any help will be well appreciated thank you so much!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var GVMaintainReceiptMaster = document.getElementById('<%= gvData.ClientID%>');
            alert("test");
            for (var rowId = 1; rowId < GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows.length; rowId++) {
                var txtbx = GVMaintainReceiptMaster.rows[rowId].cells[0].children[0];
                var readOnlyLength = $(txtbx).val().length;

                $(txtbx).on('keypress, keydown', function (event) {
                    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
                        && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
                        || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                alert(txtbx.value);

            }
```