# Javascript to validate only Numeric after predefined text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, validation, keypress

I'm trying to use Javascript to make a textbox that contains some read-only text at the beginning of the text box and then allows editing following the read-only text. I need to allow only 10 digit numeric after the readonly text and need to validate for the numeric digits. The following is the Javascript code for having the readonly in textbox

```
var readOnlyLength = $('#field').val().length;
 $('#output').text(readOnlyLength);enter code here
$('#field').on('keypress, keydown', function(event) {
var $field = $(this);
$('#output').text(event.which + '-' + this.selectionStart);
if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
    && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
    || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8)))) {
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: you can reach read only by making the input disabled.

Comment: Why not simply go for using label for the fixed text and text-box for the numeric input?

Comment: *allow only 10 digit numeric* is that fixed `10` or max `10` ?

Comment: You should be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181417/how-to-make-only-some-text-in-a-text-box-read-only-while-allowing-the-rest-to-be

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for solution with script then here is plain js and `RegExp`:

```js
var fixedText = function(textbox, label) {
  var num = textbox.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //non numeric
  num = num.substr(0, 10); //max 10 digits
  textbox.value = label + num;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="fixedText(this, 'Postal Code: ')" autofocus='' value="Postal Code: " />
<input type="text" onkeyup="fixedText(this, 'Contact No: ')" value='Contact No: ' />
```

With simple `label` ,`input` and `script`:

```js
var numeric = function(textbox) {
  var num = textbox.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  num = num.substr(0, 10);
  textbox.value = num;
};
```

```css
label.partial,
input.partial {
  border: 1px ridge grey;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
label.partial {
  border-right: none;
  cursor: text;
}
input.partial {
  border-left: none;
  margin-left: -4px;
  top: -1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<label for="PostalCode" class='partial'>Postal Code&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" onkeyup="numeric(this)" autofocus='' id='PostalCode' class='partial' />
<br/>
<label for="ContactNo" class='partial'>Contact No&nbsp;</label>
<input type="text" onkeyup="numeric(this)" id='ContactNo' class='partial' />
```