# reset textbox value on change event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and i am doing a validation on its data on input change event. 
I am checking the existence of a specific word in the text field and if this keyword is present proceed further otherwise i am showing an alert and i want to reset the value at this point

```
    <input type="text" value="$name$" id="text_messageinput" />
```

the input box will loaded with value $name$ and if user tries to edit this part of the text i have to prevent that 
 For doing so i tried this code

```
    $("#text_messageinput").on('input', function () {
        var input_value = $(this).val();
        if (input_value) {
            var inputs_ok = true;
            var selected_name = $("#chk_addname").is(":checked");
            if (selected_name == true) {
                var text_input = $("#text_messageinput").val();
                if (text_input.indexOf("$name$") === -1) {
                    alert("$name$ should be in message");
                    inputs_ok = false;
                    //i have to reset textbox value to prev value
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So how can i reset the value back when validation error occurs

Comment: Do you only want to disable textbox editing?

Comment: @xzegga NO user can edit textbox content but not the keyword. Rest all portion is editable

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181639/1057007

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help. save the old value manually and use this to reset value.

```js
$("#text_messageinput").on('input', function () {
        var input_value = $(this).val();
        if (input_value) {
            var inputs_ok = true;
            var selected_name = $("#chk_addname").is(":checked");

                var text_input = $("#text_messageinput").val();
          
                if (text_input.indexOf("$name$") === -1 || text_input == "") {
                    alert("$name$ should be in message");
                    inputs_ok = false;
                                    $("#text_messageinput").val($("#text_messageinput").attr('data'));
                }
                else
                {
                  $("#text_messageinput").attr('data',text_input);
                }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data="$name$" value="$name$" id="text_messageinput" />
```

Comment: this is something i am looking for but in my case the value is not resetting sometimes. Its showing error alert but not resetting to old state

Comment: could you share your code in a jsfiddle or stack snippet. I will have a look